# GetManifestResourceNames returns empty array

Tags: c#, xml, reflection

I am trying to load an **xml** file into a method to process it. I have two projects: `SignalServer` and `DbLibrary`. Inside `DbLibrary` there is a class `SQLQuery` that has a method `GetResourceTextFile(string xmlFile)`. This method gets called in the `SignalServer` as follows:

```
SQLQueries.GetResourceTextFile("SignalServer.HubQueries.xml");
```

Within this method i try to load the resources from the xml file:

```
using (Stream resourceStream = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()
                                                   .GetManifestResourceStream(xmlFile)){}
```

However, the `GetManifestResourceStream` does not seem to be getting any resources passed to it. In fact, when i use the following to debug:

```
string [] p = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```

The array is empty.

The file that i am trying to load is within the SignalServer directory. Why is it not seen by `GetManifestResourceStream`and how do i fix that? Thanks!

Comment: ensure the assembly is the correct one that you want. make sure the xml file is an embedded resource.

Comment: Why do you use `GetCallingAssembly`? What do you think what this method returns? (This could or could not be related to your problem, depending on how you call the method containing this code...). Also are you sure that the XML file has been added as a **manifest** resource? If so, has it been possibly added as a _private_ resource?

Comment: @DanielA.White you are right that was the issue. The property was set to None. Thanks!

Comment: The manifest step is what through me off coming from Java ecosystem. I was befuddled why my files weren't available.  Also using VS Code which requires more manual steps.  Found these links helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49479476/how-to-mark-a-file-as-an-embedded-resource-in-visual-studio-code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49784191/what-does-none-remove-mean-in-csproj