# How do I include a .jpg into a dll?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, resources, export

I have a third-party application that creates a dll file out my .cs code.

In my .cs code I reference a file.

How do I compile the dll or .cs to include the .jpg file along with the code?

The options I have for the third-party application does not allow me to export the .jpg

The import process only looks at the .cs and the associated .dll.

Is there a way to add the file to the dll once the third-party application has created the dll in the export process with visual stuido or something?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible. If the file is used by your code in the dll then the file needs to be embedded thorugh the Properties >> Build Action >> Embedded Resource setting:

[image]

#### (EDIT) Visual Studio Code variant

You have to edit the .csproj and change the node that represents your file to:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\yourEmbeddedResource.json" />
```

#### Source:

1. https://starbeamrainbowlabs.com/blog/article.php?article=posts/180-Embedding-Resources.html;
2. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114997/Embedding-and-Using-Resources-from-Net-Assembly;
3. [How to mark a file as an embedded resource in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49479476/how-to-mark-a-file-as-an-embedded-resource-in-visual-studio-code);

Comment: Thank you for this. The third-party app allows me to create my own custom code. My clients will use it to import the file, however there is no option to add resources like in visual code. Will visual code allow me to embed it on an already created dll by the third-party app?

Comment: @lakersfan . I think that's only possible when you've got the project for the dll or decompiled the existing dll so you can embed a new file into.

Comment: @lliass Nassibane  Thank you. As my orliginal file is .cs would it be doing the exact same thing in visual code? meaning if I put a .cs project in visual code, then will it also produce the same DLL once I compile?

Comment: @lakersfan I'm only familiar with creating dll's in Visual Studio. If you want to know more, then I would advice you to create a new question on stackoverflow.