# How can I load a local script using VB.Net WebView control?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, import, webview, local

I develop an application that use a `WebView` in a `WinForm` using `VB.NET`.

The HTML code displayed in `WebView` is dynamically generated using `VB.NET` code.

```
    wvSelect.Settings.IsScriptNotifyAllowed = True
    wvSelect.Settings.IsJavaScriptEnabled = True
    wvSelect.NavigateToString(sHtmlText)
```

where `sHtmlText` contains HTML tags and values.

This work well.

My HTML string is generated in a module

```
    Public eHtml =
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // script (see code below)
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
```

That's working, but Javascript code crash every time I write a `<` characters and color formatting of Javascript code is not optimal.

I know that I can use

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
// <![CDATA[

// ]]>
</script>
```

That works for `<` and `>` characters but color formatting is very bad.

So, I have decided to move all my `Javascript` code in `.JS` file.

My HTML now, look like this

```
    Public eHtml =
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="file:///D:/Documents/app.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
```

Since, I have made this change, what is displayed in WebView is different from what I obtained before !

I suppose that `.JS` file is not called, not found or something else.

You must know that just before loading HTML string in `WebView`, I save it in an .HTML file.

When I double click on this .HTML file, `Chrome` load it and what is displayed is correct.

The problem happens only when HTML string is displayed on WebView.

As you can see, I don't have any problem importing JQuery script.
This problem is only for `LOCAL` scripts.

For information, my Javascript file contains following lines (I have removed some lines)
It is just to show that JQuery is used.

```
var eUnicode;
var iCounter = 0;
var eDraggable;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.button').attr('draggable', 'True');

    $('.digit').click(function (ev) { clickDigit(ev); });

    $(".button").click(function (ev) {
        clickButton(ev.target);
    });

    showFirstTab();
});

function clickButton(eButton) {
    var sName = event.srcElement.innerText;
    hideAllOnglets();
    eButton.style.background = "orange";
    showOnglet(sName);
}

function showTab(sName) {
    var eOnglet = document.getElementById(sName);
    eOnglet.style.display = "block";
}
```

Has somebody already encountered and resolved this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem using an embedded file (VB.Net Resource).

This technic is more safe because embedded file in not modifiable by user on installation location.

The Javascript.js file is located my application file/folder tree and has been defined as `embedded resource` in `Build Action` property as explained on [How do I include a .jpg into a dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61805604/how-do-i-include-a-jpg-into-a-dll/61806512#61806512)
.

I don't use `<script src='location'>` tag because it don't work and also because HTML string is already dynamically build from my code for other part.

My VB.Net code is following

```
Private Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim reader As StreamReader
    Dim ass As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()

    sHtmlText = eHtml.ToString()
    sHtmlText = sHtmlText.Replace("(%-ONGLET-%)", sOngletText)
    sHtmlText = sHtmlText.Replace("(%-TABLE-%)", sTableText)

    reader = New StreamReader(ass.GetManifestResourceStream("UnicodeInput.JavaScript.js"))
    Dim sScriptText = reader.ReadToEnd()
    reader.Close()
    sHtmlText = sHtmlText.Replace("(%-SCRIPT-%)", sScriptText)

    reader = New StreamReader(ass.GetManifestResourceStream("UnicodeInput.StyleSheet.css"))
    Dim sStyleText = reader.ReadToEnd()
    reader.Close()
    sHtmlText = sHtmlText.Replace("(%-STYLE-%)", sStyleText)

    wvSelect.Settings.IsScriptNotifyAllowed = True
    wvSelect.Settings.IsJavaScriptEnabled = True
    wvSelect.NavigateToString(sHtmlText)

    Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
    file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("output.html", False)
    file.Write(sHtmlText)
    file.Close()
```

As you can see I have done same improvement for CSS file and I have discovered that this file has some errors !

My 'pseudo' HTML code is following

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///D:/Documents/+Informatique/Application/@Visual Basic.NET/UnicodeInput/app.js"></script>
        <script src="file:///D:/Documents/app.js"></script>
-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (%-SCRIPT-%)
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            (%-STYLE-%)
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="onglet">
            <div class='button'>Keyboard</div>
(%-ONGLET-%)
            <div class='button' onclick="GetNewCmdFile()">*ADD</div>
        </div>
```

What is in comment is what I have already tried that doesn't work in WinForm VB.Net WebView but works perfectly in pure HTML on Chrome.